# JavaScript Deferred in Custom Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I'm having problems waiting for a deferred to complete when using the deferred in the `onStepChanging` event on the jQuery plugin "jQuery-Steps". This plugin is documented at http://www.jquery-steps.com/. The step returns immediately instead of waiting for the deferred. In my real code I am doing an ajax call and I want to wait for the result before proceeding to the next step.

Here is some sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $("#form1");
    form.children("div").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
            $.when(asyncEvent()).then(function(status) {
                return status;
            });
        }
    });
});

function asyncEvent() {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function() {
        dfd.resolve(true);
    }, 2000);

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is you ajax too complex to use the [built in async features](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#async)?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the relevant markup?

Comment: Is you ajax too complex to use the built in async features? Yes, it is more complicated than just pointing to a URL.

Can you provide a snippet of the relevant markup? I'm not sure how much more markup I can provide that would add value.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is expecting an asynchronous function to return synchronously and this will not work. Here is an alternative approach that will disable changing steps until the promise has completed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $("#form1");
    // initialize the return value as false (since you want to wait for your promise to complete)
    var stepReady = false;
    form.children("div").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
            $.when(asyncEvent()).then(function(status) {
                stepReady = status;
            });
            return stepReady;
        }
    });
});

function asyncEvent() {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function() {
        dfd.resolve(true);
    }, 2000);

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

It would be better in this instance to use `done` directly on the returned promise since the purpose of `then` is to manipulate the state. So, it would change to:

```
onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
    asyncEvent().done(function(status) {
        stepReady = status;
    });
    return stepReady;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it still immediately goes to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

The step run immediately without waiting for your deferred because **$.when** is run asynchronously and in your script you are return **status** for **$.when** callback not for **onStepChanging**.

My suggestion, yo need to **return false** your **onStepChanging** event by default, and do step change manually..

may be something like this

```
onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
    $.when(asyncEvent()).then(function(status) {
        if(status)
        {
            if (currentIndex < newIndex)
            {
                form.children("div").steps('next');
            }
            else
            {
                form.children("div").steps('previous');
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Sorry if I write some mistake, I'm not testing this code well, I just read example on http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples and try to understand how it work, but the main idea is just return false by default and do step change manually.. Hope it help..

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I gave it a shot and there are two issues. First, when false is returned a CSS class called "error" is added to the navigation link. This is easily overcome by editing the "error" CSS class. The second issue I could not overcome - it runs the "onStepChanging" event even when changing steps though the "next" method. This causes an endless loop.